# Compile a project using PIXI.js in ADVANCED mode with Closure Compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler, pixi.js

I am trying to compile a project which is using a pixi.js library with closure compiler in ADVANCED mode as advised here:

`You should not include a minified version of pixi during your minifying process.
Instead, you can try to include the unminified version.`
https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1097

I am using this file (please correct me is this is not the right one):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixijs/pixi.js/master/bin/pixi.js

and the latest compiler ( v20151015 )

```
--summary_detail_level 3
--warning_level VERBOSE
--compilation_level ADVANCED
--source_map_format V3
--js ... ( project files here, including pixi.js )
--js_output_file Output.min.js
```

The compilation errors on:

```
lib/pixi.js:35: ERROR - variable exports is undeclared
(function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined"){module.exports=f()}else
```

Just as an experiment I added @fileoverview to see what I will get

```
/**
* @fileoverview
* @suppress {unknownDefines|checkTypes|checkVars|misplacedTypeAnnotation|nonStandardJsDocs|suspiciousCode|checkVars|accessControls|ambiguousFunctionDecl|deprecatedAnnotations|missingReturn|newCheckTypes}
*/
```

The output I am getting is 412 warnings (all inside Pixi):

```
0 error(s), 412 warning(s), 61.8% typed
```

I am not sure if I am using the correct pixi.js file, The pixi.dev.js file, which @sbondor is talking about, is not online any more:

https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1260

So, what am I doing wrong?
How can I compile a project inlcuding pixi.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that PIXI.js is compatible with the `ADVANCED` mode of the compiler.

However, a quick glance shows me a few things you'll need to use to try:

#### --process_common_js_modules

PIXI uses a Universal Module Definition for some of it's files. The compiler can remove and rewrite some UMD module wrappers, but you'll need to specify the `--process_common_js_modules` flag. That will also take care of the `variable exports is undeclared` warnings.

#### --common_js_entry_module

You'll need to specify the entry module for your application with this flag. It's the base file for your application.

Comment: The `--process_common_js_modules` flag enables dependency pruning in the compiler. That means I think you'd have to go fully towards using commonjs modules (require.js is AMD modules - not the same thing). The compiler CAN translate some AMD modules to common js, but I think at that point you are just going down a rabbit hole.

Comment: So what would you recommend? Should I write the externs file for pixi and include minified pixi library after compilation, instead of going down the rabbit hole? I have not used commonjs before, but I don't mind learning it and adapting the project if you think this will work.

Comment: I suppose the externs is the answer.

Comment: Yes - I think externs is the answer